# Display:none to image if class

Tags: css

I use the code above to display pdf icon before each pdf file to download.

```
a[href*="pdf"]::before {
    content: url('../gfx/pdficon.png');
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I have problem when the icon appear with objects like img, at which I do not want this icon. 
I came up with the idea to create a class "nopdf" to add to images to be without this icon.

How can I apply it in css? I guess that is enough to "display:none", but how to construct a rule css in this case?

EDIT: Problem is only when I link (href) to image. Then before image I see pdf icon.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create class "pdf" instead which you add to the pdfs only?

Comment: Why will the icon appear on `img`s when your selector is `a[href*="pdf"]` which means it will only apply to `a`s?

Comment: I guess he means img tags inside an a tag

Comment: @Esko I don't want to tag each pdf by class. In my case each href pdf file have icon automatically.

Comment: @ArnelleBalane if the link refers to an image named mypdf.jpg, the selector will match.

Comment: @ArnelleBalane - the problem is when I link (href) image to pdf file - then before image I see also pdf icon.

Comment: @Pat Why not? Why do you want to do it backwards, first adding pdf-icon to everything then removing it from images? Sounds more complicated, not to mention inefficient css-selector. But yes you can do it either way, just not what I would do.

Comment: @Esko my rule works great on whole site - I link only text, so I have icon before it. I do not have to do anything else. But if I need to link pdf file to image I would like to avoid display this icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.nopdf::before {
  display: none !important;
}
```

or you just extend your existing rule like so:

```
a[href*="pdf"]:not( .nopdf )::before {
    content: url('../gfx/pdficon.png');
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? One of those 2 solutions? Or both solutions? How does your HTML look like?

Comment: Both solutions. It is wordpress, here you can see how the piece of code looks https://s10.postimg.org/9xwajsovt/code.png

Comment: Ah ok. You need to add the `nopdf`-class to the link itself. Not the image. If that is not possible you need to have a JS-script that does it for you. There is currently no way to style an element based on its child